# Attempting to write a KIVY hello world app through my iPhone using Pyto IDE, error?

Tags: python, kivy

trying to write and deploy a simple hello world app through my iPhone. I have only a windows computer and I want to write a simple iPhone app so I figured I could do so on my iPhone since it is using iOS architecture. When I run this simple Hello-World app through an Python IDE app called Pyto I get an error message.

Here is the Kivy Hello World code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
 
 
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And here is the error on my iPhone using the app Pyto:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "iCloud/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
from kivy.app import App
File "Documents/site-package/kivy/__init__.py", line 338, in <module>
mkdir(kivy_home_dir)
permissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted '.kivy'
```

Any and all help are welcome!

THANKS!

Comment: Kivy is trying to access a directory that doesn't exist or at least isn't writable. Probably Kivy isn't detecting that you're running on an iOS device. You can probably fix that, but before trying you should check that Pyto actually supports Kivy. If it doesn't, Kivy simply won't work, it depends on iOS backend stuff that is not pure Python and won't be available in a generic python environment.

Comment: We’re you able to find a solution to this? Same issue and I’d like to use Pyto on my iPad to save booting my pi up all the time when I’m on the go and want to do some dev work.